# WinForms Application on Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi-os, c#, mono

Im running Raspberry Pi OS (formerly Raspbian) on a RaspberryPi. I have to develop a WinForms app. RaspberryPi OS is based on Debian. This means I can use the .NET Core SDK (via a snap package). Or I can use the Mono project (via a deb package). Can I use .NET Core to develop a WinForms app?

Answer (score 0):

**No.** The snaps `dotnet-sdk` and `dotnet-runtime` (both with optional version suffix) as well as the corresponding deb packages do not allow to create WinForms apps. To get the available project type use `dotnet new --list`.